# drizzle port http://0.0.0.0:4983/ not working (This site can’t be reached)

Tags: typescript, port, database-schema, next.js13, drizzle

I run this command `npx drizzle-kit studio` and it showing like this:

> No config path provided, using default path
> Reading config file 'A:\Mern Stack\Next js\kanoon-ai\drizzle.config.ts'
>
> [Warning] Drizzle Studio is currently in Beta. If you find anything that is not working as expected or should be improved, feel free to create an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-kit-mirror/issues/new or write to us on Discord: https://discord.gg/WcRKz2FFxN
>
> Drizzle Studio is up and running on [http://0.0.0.0:4983`](http://0.0.0.0:4983%60)

but Chrome is showing :

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:4983/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

My drazzile.config.ts file:

```
import type { Config } from "drizzle-kit";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: ".env" });

export default {
  driver: "pg",
  schema: "./src/lib/db/schema.ts",
  dbCredentials: {
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL!,
  },
} satisfies Config;
```

How can I get rid of this?

What should I change in my code?

Comment: Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1:4983`?

Comment: Related - https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this (or crying emoticons) to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is true but if you open up http://localhost:4983, it will work.

however, i'd also like the terminal to print http://localhost:4983 (i don't like 0.0.0.0 for some reason)

and this doesn't print http://localhost:3001 either which i guess it should:

drizzle-kit studio --host localhost --port 3001 --verbose --config drizzle.config.ts
it instead prints http://[::1]:3001 which is weird. idk if this is a syntax for ipv6 or something.

Comment: This seems like a new question? But it was posted as an answer.